# MSSQLToGCSOperator how to create empty file into bucket

Tags: bucket

we upgrade composer (1.19.13) and aiflow (2.3.3) version at GCP cloud.
in our previous version if the query does not return any data, there is a file empty created by the MSSQLToGCSOperator. But now when query return no data, there is no file created (empty file) into GCP bucket, and I got an error of file not found, at the following task.

I try this code:

```
  mssql_to_gcs = MSSQLToGCSOperator(
        task_id='MYSQL_TO_GCS_{0}'.format(TABLE_NAME),
        mssql_conn_id='con_mssql_dba_prd',
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_storage_default',    
        sql='select_{0}.sql'.format(TABLE_NAME),
        bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET,
        filename='composer/{0}/gcp_{0}{1}.json'.format(TABLE_NAME, DATE_FORMAT),
        dag=dag
     )

using this operator: 

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.mssql_to_gcs import MSSQLToGCSOperator
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the write_on_empty parameter for the SQL to GCS operator and set to True.  The default is now False.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28806

e.g.:

```
    mssql_to_gcs = MSSQLToGCSOperator(
    task_id='MYSQL_TO_GCS_{0}'.format(TABLE_NAME),
    mssql_conn_id='con_mssql_dba_prd',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_storage_default',    
    sql='select_{0}.sql'.format(TABLE_NAME),
    bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET,
    write_on_empty=True,
    filename='composer/{0}/gcp_{0}{1}.json'.format(TABLE_NAME, 
    DATE_FORMAT),
    dag=dag
    )
```